# Making an Alarm Clock with multiple alarm times

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a programmable alarm clock. It should output a melody (.wav) at different moments of time. I used a usercontrol to make a digital clock. I have a timer for showing a progressbar to every second and a button that starts the process. I know exactly the times I want so I don't need any other button. I made some functions where I complete the times I need.

```
public void suna3()
{
    userControl11.Ora = 01;
    userControl11.Min = 37;
    userControl11.Sec = 50;
}
```

and on the button click I called them. But when I start the program it is taking only the last time I made (the last function). How can I make it take all the functions?

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    userControl11.Activ = true;
    suna1();

    userControl11.Activ = true;
    suna2();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you make it more clear?

Comment: What do you want it to do with the multiple times? Display them in different controls at the same time? Count them down after each other?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand, can you post more code?  For example, what is in suna1() and suna2()?

Comment: Do you mean "how to make automatic controls refreshing"?

Answer (score 2):

I *think* the problem is that you are using the same timer for three different events, changing the settings of it three times. This results in only the final settings being used - the older settings are not remembered - they are overwritten.

The solution is to create a new timer for each event, each timer having its own separate settings.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `usercontrol` for each alarm time, or change your user control so that it takes in an array of times to trigger the alarm at.

For multiple `usercontrol` instances, your code could look something like this:

```
public void suna1()
{
    userControl11.Ora = 02;
    userControl11.Min = 27;
    userControl11.Sec = 20;
}

//...

public void suna3()
{
    userControl13.Ora = 01;
    userControl13.Min = 37;
    userControl13.Sec = 50;
}
```

The alternative is to change your `usercontrol` so that it accepts a list of times, or has an `AddAlarm()` method. Something like this:

```
public void suna1()
{
    userControl11.Alarms.Add(new Alarm() { Ora = 02, Min = 27, Sec = 20 };
    //or "userControl1.AddAlarm(2, 27, 20);" if you go the method route
}

//...

public void suna3()
{
    userControl11.Alarms.Add(new Alarm() { Ora = 01, Min = 37, Sec = 50 };
}
```